# Why does mysql_connect break my .php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

I have the following code running on Apache 2.2 with PHP 5.3.3:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "Connecting...";

$conn = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3306','root','*******') or die('Error connecting to mysql');

echo 'Connected.';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And it prints out "Connecting...", but nothing else. Doesn't even throw an error. I went through all the steps that were obvious. help?

Comment: Segfault in the php-mysql extension?  I'm not sure.  You might have to check your Apache logs.

Comment: You shouldn't connect as root. You probably know it though. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`error_reporting(E_ALL);` might sometimes not do it. Use it in combination with:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and see if it returns an error then :)

Comment: +1 If `display_errors` is set to *off* and the mysql extension is not loaded, you can get the symptoms described.

Comment: That. Is so. Weird. I specifically set display_errors to on IN ALL CASES in my php.ini. Perhaps its using a different one... or not. I don't have another. Anyways, this worked. I get "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in *****.php on line 15. Buh. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Test skipping the port notation since you are specifying the default port anyways.

What does your Apache error log say?

What does var_dump($conn) print out?

Comment: OK I see. It shouldn't make any difference but it's just something I would test when debugging to see if there's an error in the MySQL library. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3306','root','*******')
if (!$conn ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($conn );
?>
```

Comment: close should probably reference `$conn` not `$link`.